# Best way to layout mySQL Database for my Project Manager

Tags: mysql

I am making a project manager site for my personal use, and I have a question about what would be the best way to build the database for the site.

It will involve `Client` list, `Projects` and `Tasks`, `Invoicing` and `Payments`.
I am trying to figure out the best way to make sure I can link all content to the `Client`.
This is what I put together in notepad just to get an idea on how my database should look like.

```
Clients: id, name
Projects: id, client, project_name, due_date
Tasks: id, client, project_name, task, due_date, complete
Invoices: invoice_id, client, project_name, date, due, balance, payment, pay_date
Invoice_item: id, item, amount
```

If anyone has a better idea on how I should do this, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: best thing to do would be download [dia](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dia-installer/) or similar, grab a few beers and go from there :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@GuberX - Why do each of the tables have just `id`?

It would look more descriptive to do something like:

```
[Client]: cliID, name
[Project]: projID, client, project_name, due_date
[Task]: taskID, client, project_name, task, due_date, complete
[Invoice]: invID, client, project_name, date, due, balance, payment, pay_date
[Invoice_item]: InvItemID, item, amount
```

An example using the foreign keys you specified (in the comments):

```
multiple tasks, single invoice but accept multiple payments

Task [taskID, client, project_name, task, due_date, complete, *projID]
```

Note the *projID above.  Further reading for you [here](http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~bernatja/crowsfoot.html)

Comment: Haha. Funny how different conventions are. I'm from a Ruby mentality where tables are always plural and the primary key is almost always just 'id' because it's for that table. Same with _on for dates and _at for datetimes / times.

Comment: i use the plain ol' "id" cuz its mainly just the primary key, and a easy way to link a specific table together. and yeah i dont use plural names for tables...  as for the foreign keys, umm ive never used one i dont think.

Comment: Guber - do you plan to have multiple tasks for a given project? or a client can have multiple invoices?

Comment: Yeah, that is where you need foreign keys. See my edited answer.

Comment: so add the projID to my task table and link it with the foreign key?

Answer (score 0):

```
Clients: id, name
Projects: id, client_id, name, due_on
Tasks: id, client_id, project_id, name, due_on, completed_at
Invoices: id, project_id, issued_on, due_on, balance, payment, paid_on
Invoice_item: id, invoice_id, item, amount
```

Client name/id not stored on invoice table as its looked up through projects.
Also considder if you want to track part payment of invoices or multiple project_milestones (deadlines) - if so then these will each need a table.

Oh yes and don't forget project statuses and their effects: quoted, won, lost, finished etc.

Comment: for my statuses im using a progress bar that is calculated from the tasks for that job. all my jobs will have more than 5 tasks usually